# Flash developers: what versions of Flash do you test your stuff with?

Tags: flash, gnash

I'm curious as to what versions of Flash stuff is tested with. How do you manage it across different browsers?

I'm wanting to test things with both swfdec and gnash and hoping maybe there's some way I didn't know about...

Answer (score 1):

All the test i run are made over IE 7, Firefox 2 and 3, Safari, Google Chrome and the Stand Alone Player. The Flash Player version i use was 9 (always the last version) and now i use Flash Player 10. Sometimes i come back with the 9 version, but always you can ask to update the flash player version.

Answer (score 0):

When i was working in the software quality team at my old part-time, we usually tested all the versions possible to guarantee that some old legacy problem wouldn't appear.

If you want to do some serious testing then i would suggest you to test on:

- IE 6 and 7
- Firefox 2 and 3
- Safari
- Rotate flash versions on all of them to guarantee sustainability.

I dunno any automated tool though :x

Answer (score 0):

I am not doing much Flash development yet, but I've decided to target Flash 7, which means testing on 7, 8, 9, and 10.  You can [download previous versions of Flash for testing](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14266&sliceId=1).

Answer (score 0):

We target version 8, and test in 8 and 9 (and now 10) using virtual machines, to avoid having to uninstall and reinstall Flash over and over again.

With more restrictive default cross domain policies coming, it's best to test using the debugger versions of the player, which implement these more restrictive policies earlier than the standard releases do, so you'll know you'll be ready for the future.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html